# How to turn on syntax highlighting for vi/vim?

Tags: centos, vi, syntax-highlighting

Running a minimal ISO of CentOS_7

I've tried writing a .sh script using vi but can't get syntax highlighting to work.

Pressing escape and typing `:syntax on` as shown in articles like [this one](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-or-off-color-syntax-highlighting-in-vi-or-vim/) are not working.

The files I'm creating and editing are definitely `.sh` files and all have `#!/bin/bash` at the start of the first line.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem is your `vim` version: probably doesn't include *syntax highlighting*; try this:

```
yum install vim-enhanced
```